# Passing multiple file names to shell script from java

Tags: shell, unix

I want to pass multiple filenames (7 to 10) to a shell script from java code.The filenames are fetched from Database depending on conditions, so the number of files is not fixed. The max will be 10 file names.

In the shell script i want to copy all these files to a different directory.

What i am doing is

cp -p "$@" /dir/temp/

But this dosent seem to work.
I am a newbie in unix and shell scripting.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If so, what are they? What happens if you run the script directly from the shell? Does the user running the java code have write access to /dir/temp/?

Comment: 1) Do the paths to the source files, or the source files themselves, contain any spaces in their names? 2) If you re-run a failed session, but include the line `echo "$@"`, what does that say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop where the contents of $@ is copied one by one